# Xtext: Cannot resolve reference

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext, metamodel

I have the following Xtext grammar:

```
grammar dsl.miniproject.Question2.EclipsePluginLanguage with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

import "platform:/resource/Question2/model/EclipsePluginModel.ecore" 
import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

Plugin:
    {Plugin}
    'Plugin' Name = EntityName
    '{'             
        (documentation = Documentation)?
        (functions += Functionality)*
        manifest = Manifest
    '}'
;

Documentation:
    {Documentation}
    'description =' documentation = STRING
;

Manifest:
    {Manifest}
    'manifest'
    '{'
        (dependencies += Dependency)*
        (extensionPoints += ExtensionPoint)*    
        (extensions += Extension)*
    '}'
;

Functionality:
    {Functionality}
    'function' Name = EntityName ';'
;

Dependency:
    {Dependency}
    Name = EntityName '=>' depends = [Plugin|EntityName]
;

Extension:
    {Extension}
    Name = EntityName '->' extends = [ExtensionPoint|EntityName]
;

ExtensionPoint:
    {ExtensionPoint}
    'ExtensionPoint' Name = EntityName 
    '{'
        'ref' functions += [Functionality|EntityName] ';'       
    '}'
;

EntityName:
    ID ('.' ID)*
;
```

However when writing a sample script ex:

```
    Plugin x{
        description = "test"

        function f;
        function f2;

        manifest{

            dep1 => x

            ExtensionPoint ep.ep1{
                ref f;
            }

            ext1 -> ep.ep1
        }    
}
```

I get the following error:

> Couldn't resolve reference to Plugin 'x'.
>   Couldn't resolve reference to Functionality 'f'.
>   ... etc

This is my first attempt at xtext and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi you should name you elements name attribute `name` and NOT `Name`
and you have to make sure the (actual) qualified names in the scope at the place you use it match the terminal or datatype rule you use (in your case `EntityName`) alternatively you can change `IQualifiedNameProvider`